# C# получить адрес последовательности байтов в памяти процесса

Tags: c#, winapi, память, byte

Программы вроде CheatEngine запросто находят последовательность байтов за долю секунды.
[image: Скрин]

Каким образом это возможно реализовать на C#? Пробовал через WINAPI перебирать каждый байт памяти, потом сравнивать его с каждым байтом последовательности в итоге аналогичная операция выполняется полчаса вместо секунды.
Помогите разобраться, сам упёрся в тупик и не могу разобраться как так.

upd: код:

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("witcher")[0];
    IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);

    uint PTR = 0x0DEB0000; //begin of memory
    byte[] bitSearch = { 0xA8, 0x04, 0x10, 0x00 }; //your bit array until ??
    byte[] buff = new byte[bitSearch.Length];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while (PTR != 0xFF000000)   //end of memory // u can specify to read less if u know he does not fill it all
    {
        ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, (int)PTR, buff, buff.Length, ref bytesRead);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buff));
        if (buff== bitSearch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PTR);
        }

        PTR += 0x1;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: 1) Такое, наверное, лучше писать на с++ 2) у вас ваш код работает медленно, но вы его не покажете?

Comment: @tym32167 С++ не желательно.

Answer (score 1):

Я предполагаю, что узким горлышком в данной ситуации служит использование readprocessmemory малыми порциями.
Попробуйте прочитать большой кусок памяти в буфер, и уже по буферу пройтись циклом и найти необходимое смещение.